# ¿Evitar editar o eliminar registros de una base de datos agregados con Seed desde la interfaz?

Tags: laravel-7

Necesito saber como puedo evitar que desde la interfaz, se editen o eliminen los datos que ya están agregados en una tabla de la base de datos por Seeder, pero que al agregar datos manualmente si me permita eliminar y editar los que se crean desde la interfaz.

Este es el controlador que actualmente tengo bajo el nombre de Vaccine

```
public function delete_vaccines(Request $request, Vet $vet)
{
    
    $request->validate([
        'ids' => 'required|array|min:1',
    ]);
    $ids = $request->get('ids');
  
    VaccineType::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->where('vet_id', Session::get('vet'))
    ->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('alerts', [
        ['type' => 'warning', 'text' => vsprintf(__('Registros eliminados %d'), [ count($ids) ]), 'title' => __('Vacunas')]
    ]);
}

/**
 * Formulario de creación o edición de vacunas
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @param App\Models\Vet $vet
 * @param App\Models\Vaccine $vaccine
 */
public function vaccine(Request $request, Vet $vet, VaccineType $vaccine=null)
{

    $vaccine = $vaccine ?? new VaccineType(['vet_id' => $vet->id]);
    

    $json_request = $request->wantsJson();
    $title = vsprintf(__('%s de tipos de vacunas'), [ $vaccine->id ? __('Edición') : __('Registro') ]);
    $view = view('admin.config.vaccines.form' . ($json_request ? "" : "_page"), compact('vet', 'vaccine', 'title', 'json_request'));
    return $json_request ? response()->json(['html' => $view->render(), 'title' => $title]) : $view;
}

/**
 * Creación o edición de vacunas
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @param App\Models\Vet $vet
 * @param App\Models\Vaccine $vaccine
 */
public function vaccine_save(Request $request, Vet $vet, VaccineType $vaccine=null)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        //'category' => 'required|max:191',
        'name' => 'required|max:191',
    ]);
    $vaccine = $vaccine ?? new VaccineType(['vet_id' => $vet->id]);

    $vaccine->fill($data);
    $vaccine->saveOrFail();

    return redirect()->back()->with('alerts', [
        ['text' => __('Vacuna registrada'), 'title' => __('Correcto')]
    ]);
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda y sus aportes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar añadir una columna a la tabla donde tienes los datos:

```js
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddFromSeederToVaccinesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('vaccines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('from_seeder')->default(0);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('vaccines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

En el Seeder defines ese atributo y así todos tendrán ese attributo boolean que indica que viene de un seeder.

```js
<?php

use App\Vaccine;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class VaccinesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Care::create(['attribute1' => 'Something', 'from_seeder' => 1]);
    }
}
```

De esa forma, cuando agreguen una nueva vacuna y no se defina la columna `from_seedeer` tendrá por defecto el valor de 0.

En tu vista puedes controlar que la forma en la que pueden seleccionar las vacunas para eliminar, por ejemplo, si usas checkboxes para seleccionar lo que se puede borrar, usarías un `@if($vaccines->from_seeder)` para condicionar la renderización del checkbox que selecciona la vacuna.

También puedes validar en tu controlador si así lo deseas:

```js
public function delete_vaccines(Request $request, Vet $vet)
{
    
    $request->validate([
        'ids' => 'required|array|min:1',
    ]);
    $ids = $request->get('ids');
  
    $vaccines = VaccineType::whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->where('vet_id', session('vet'))->get()
    
    $errors = [];
    foreach($vaccines as $vaccine) {
      if($vaccine->from_seeder){
        $errors[] = "La vacuna con el ID " . $vaccine->id . " no puede ser eliminada porque es fija"
      } else {
        $vaccine->delete();
      }
    }
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('messages', $errors);
    ]);
}
```

Y listo :)

Answer (score -1):

Excelente, me ayudo muchísimo tu respuesta y funciono, pero de igual manera tendría que hacer un condicional o validación para evitar que me inyecten código SQL desde el lado del servidor, ya que desde la interfaz ya no permite eliminar o editar, sin embargo al realizarlo por "inspeccionar" puedo modificar los datos y cambiar el ID para que sea editable o me permita eliminar y eso es lo que quiero prevenir.

Comment: Si quieres evitar ese tipo de inyección, te recomiendo usar la solución que te describí en la segunda parte de mi respuesta. Haciendo todo del lado del servidor, verificas la nueva columna en tu BD y quedas cubierto de eso.

Si te sirvió, te pido considerar votar arriba y marcar como correcta mi respueta. 

Saludos